# Does values standardization affect its distrution?

Tags: monte-carlo, standardization, wald-test

I have Wald's test results from comparing sensitivity and specificity of LDA and QDA. Results are almost the same.

I generate data, train and classify it and then obtain the Wald statistic. I need to do it N times.

After that, its (Wald's test) distribution has to follow N(0, 1) according to an article I got info from.

But in my case it doesn't follow it (I think because the difference between LDA and QDA is negligible).

If I standardize that distribution, it will follows N(0,1).

Can I just standardize data and claim that my origin data (before standardizing) follows N(0,1)? If yes, Is there any articles that approve this fact?

Comment: I can't follow what you're doing here. But note that $z = (x - $ mean) ./ SD has mean $0$ and SD $1$ but is normally distributed only if $x$ is normally distributed. If that's not the problem, you need a different answer.

Answer (score 1):

Standardization only scales and shifts your data, so your mean ends up to be 0 and the sd ends up to be 1. If your data was normally distributed before, you end up with your data following N(0,1). If it wasn't normally distributed, it still won't be after normalization. You'll just have a mean of 0 and an sd of 1, but it could still be heavily skewed for example. You would need a different transformation, depending on the empirical distribution of your dataset. Whether it would make any sense in your case, I can't judge, it's not really clear to me what you are trying to do.

Comment: I assume that data before standartization follows N(0, 1) as well, but there aren't enough evidence for it due to its nature (I compare 2 classifiers N times, but they are so close to each other that Wald test gives almost identical results each time)  (is it even possible to say like that?).
After standartization it follows N(0, 1) anyways.